# gedit window buttons are on the wrong side?

Tags: 16.04, gedit, window, ubuntu-mate

In Ubuntu Mate windows have their buttons (close, maximize, minimize) on the left side. The application Gedit, however, has these buttons on the right side. I haven't been able to find a fix for this via searching. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Version info

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ gedit --version
gedit - Version 3.18.3

$ dpkg -s gedit
Package: gedit
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Installed-Size: 1732
Maintainer: Ubuntu Desktop Team <ubuntu-desktop@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.18.3-0ubuntu4
…
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not providing it at first. I've added it to the original question, and can add more info as requested. Must go now for a bit, will be back later. Thanks!

Comment: My standard 16.04 installation Gedit buttons are on the left, as expected.  What package are you running for gedit?  Mine is 3.18.3-0ubuntu4

Comment: I'm assuming you've installed a gnome program, which has it's buttons on the right side.

Comment: @Dooley_labs: I suppose gedit is a gnome program? but it is the only one that is placing its buttons in the wrong place.

Comment: @ubfan1: gedit version appears to be the same as yours

Comment: You guys have the same version, but it looks like one of you has the gnome version and the other has the Mate version. That's just my guess, but what's @AndroidDev 's output when they do `dpkg -s gedit`? I wonder if one says `Section: gnome` and the other says `Section: mate`. I'll check my Mate install and report back. EDIT: upon checking said command, I've discovered I was wrong. It also says gnome.

Comment: @Dooley_labs: if gedit did not come installed with ubuntu-mate, I would have installed it via 'sudo apt-get install gedit' or similar. Perhaps there is a different package that contains a version that has been set up to be compatible with mate then?

Comment: Same for my standard gedit. On my XFCE install, there's a program called `mousepad`. It looks to be the same as gedit, but without the buttons.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that the answer is: gnome programs do not play well with the mate environment? But surely there is a configuration option to get gnome apps to place window buttons on the left? Or perhaps I can just move Mate buttons to the right; either way.